# R Data Cleaning Challenge - What is the best way to find and replace string matches across multiple columns of data?

Tags: r, gsub, data-cleaning

I have a marketing dataset where each customer has 3 parameters:

- utm_source
- utm_medium
- utm_campaign

The data set looks like this:

```
Id  utm_source  utm_medium  utm_campaign
11  internet    google+ppc  unknown
23  internet    organic home
31  internet    organic home
35  internet    google+ppc  unknown
37  internet    google+ppc  unknown
```

The data has a parent-child, grand-child relationship like this:

**utm_source (parent) -> utm_medium (child) -> utm_capaign (grand-child)**

The problem I have is that some of these parent-child relationship have changed.

**Thus, I need to clean the old data to match the new utm structure.**

For example,

**OLD:**

```
Id  utm_source  utm_medium  utm_campaign
11  internet    google+ppc  unknown
```

**NEW:**

```
Id  utm_source  utm_medium  utm_campaign
11  internet    paid    google
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this difficult data-cleaning problem in R?

Comment: You can try `fuzzyjoin::regex_join`. Or you can use `dplyr::case_when`. Or you can use `forcats::fct_recode`. Many good tools.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll give these a shot.

Comment: Yeedle - Could you elaborate on how you would use fuzzyjoin solve this problem? Would you combine the 3 columns into one column and then use a fuzzy matching dictionary to replace the old values with new values?

Comment: If you can please provide a reproducible example in your question (the current data frame and the expected result) I'll be better able to answer more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
data$utm_medium <- gsub("google+ppc", "paid", data$utm_medium)
data$utm_campaign <- gsub("unknown", "google", data$utm_campaign)
```